# Time integration - time "direction"

Tags: functions, definite-integrals

I am wondering, why we integrate functions of the time in the following manner:

$$\int_0^t q({\tau})p(t - {\tau}) d{\tau} $$

it seems the  $ p(t - {\tau} ) $ is integrated in the "other direction" of time flow than $q({\tau})$, simply because as ${\tau}$ progresses through time, the $q({\tau})$ it being incremented, while for $ p(t - {\tau} )$ is being decremented.

WHY is that ? What are implications to real-world application ? (By The Way, I have lectures from Control Theory and it seems like this is the way to do stuff) WHY ?

What is the difference if both $q()$ and $p()$ are integrated in the same "direction" of time, such that

$$\int_0^t q({\tau})p({\tau}) d{\tau} $$

it seems like the result would be completely different.

Comment: I would appreciate simple clarification with some real-world application

Comment: Is that supposed to be $d\tau$ not $dx$ then?

Comment: thank you, it is corrected now

Comment: You might be interested in looking at [this site](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs178-10/applets/convolution.html) for an application of convolution to image processing. (Oh, I just read that you are more interested in time applications... Nevertheless, I let this comment stand)

Answer (score 0):

This type of relation occurs if one studies the linear response of a system
to some cause. The standard example is the response of a dielectric to an
electric field. There $q$ is the electric field and $p$ the susceptibility. But
note that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{t}dsq(s)p(t-s)=\int_{0}^{t}dsq(t-s)p(s)
\end{equation*}
In general we have
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dsp(t,s)q(s)
\end{equation*}
But if we have time-translation invariance this becomes
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dsp(t-s)q(s)
\end{equation*}
In addition we require the response not to preceed the cause so
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty }^{t}dsp(t-s)q(s)
\end{equation*}
and if we switch on $q$ at time $t=0$
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{t}dsp(t-s)q(s)
\end{equation*}
which is your expression. Your final expression
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{t}dsp(s)q(s)
\end{equation*}
does not seem to have an interpretation along these lines.